# Get direct link from a soundcloud for use in download managers

Tags: links, url, download, soundcloud

There's a sound clip on soundcloud that has a "download" button.. It's a large mp3 (150 MB+), when I click it, download starts on the crappy chrome and due to some reason, it got stuck at 60%.

Now I want to resume this now. I've known that wget and other download managers can resume such failed downloads (in this case, .crdownload files), so I went on to [grab the direct link](https://superuser.com/a/27246/77978) for soundcloud.. The closest I could get was to initiate a new download in chrome, and in "Downloads" section, find the download and right click > *copy link address*. I used this in both wget (with -c parameter) and Free Download Manager.. none of them work. Here's what FDM gave:-

```
AM 10:23:35 18/05/2013 Starting download...
AM 10:23:36 18/05/2013 Access denied. Invalid user name or password
AM 10:23:36 18/05/2013 Stopped
```

Is there any way to get a proper download link of soundcloud so it can work on external download managers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [Offliberty](http://offliberty.com/) website. Copy the URL and paste it into the big bar inside the website and hit the button.  You will get video and mp3 download links.

Answer (score 0):

download the file using chrome... press `ctrl+J` to open **download tab** from where you can access the download link easily....

also..if the file is less than 100mbs big, use [this site](http://www.online-convert.com) to convert it into a zip which will be *directly linkable and resumable*...